# Replacing missing values in a specific column with different values - Rstudio/R

Tags: r, replace, missing-data

I have a dataset consisting of 638 datapoints and 79 variables, where one of the columnns is called "home_indicator" that is a dummy variable with the value home or away.
However, there are several NA's in the column which i want to randomly replace with either home or away (a 50/50 split is completely fine). However, I'm quite new to R and have only managed to replace the value with either home or away. I dont want it conditioned to other coefficients' value in the dataset.

Can any1 give me a hint or maybe an example on how to fix this? :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:10, c2 = letters[1:10], c3 = c(sample(c('home','away', NA), 10, T)))
df
   c1 c2   c3
1   1  a <NA>
2   2  b away
3   3  c home
4   4  d <NA>
5   5  e home
6   6  f home
7   7  g away
8   8  h <NA>
9   9  i <NA>
10 10  j home
df$c3[is.na(df$c3)] <- sample(c('home','away'), sum(is.na(df$c3)), T)
df
   c1 c2   c3
1   1  a home
2   2  b away
3   3  c home
4   4  d home
5   5  e home
6   6  f home
7   7  g away
8   8  h home
9   9  i away
10 10  j home
```